# WP7.5 BCL Async: await not waiting

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, async-await

I've installed the BCL Async prerelease bits into my WP7 app, and I've added an async call to an async Task like this:

```
await GetStuff();
// do stuff
```

where GetStuff is async Task.

however, this appears to not be "awaiting" but rather it immediately skips to the next line of code, so the stuff it's supposed to be acting on isn't there yet because the async task hasn't completed.

Am I misunderstanding how this library works? My understanding is that it adds the await functionality similar to WinRT or WP8 so that it will wait for that async task to complete before continuing execution.

If this IS what it's supposed to do, what might I be doing wrong here?

Comment: `GetStuff()` is probably wrong.

Comment: 1) [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) is no longer prerelease; please upgrade. 2) WP7 is not a supported platform; perhaps you meant WP7.5? 3) @SLaks is probably right; please post the code for `GetStuff` and describe what you meant for it to do.

Comment: i did mean 7.5 sorry, will update the post. I'll update too and see if it's resolved otherwise report back, thanks for the tips fellas!

Comment: Slaks was right, I had an async call inside GetStuff() that I forgot to include the await keyword. If you can post this as an answer I'd be happy to accept it as such, otherwise I'll post it when it lets me, thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would happen if the task returned by `GetStuff()` doesn't wait for everything to finish (eg, if you forgot an `await`).